# Can I configure separate S3 buckets in Refile initializer for different functionalities in a Rails 4 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, refile

I am using Refile gem to upload images on S3 in Rails 4 project. My requirement is to upload images for separate functionalities into two separate buckets on S3.

However, I could find documentation for setting up only one bucket. Is there anyway I can configure multiple S3 buckets with Refile?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Simone's information, I implemented the code in my own project so it effectively works.

`Refile.store` and `Refile.cache` are included in Refile's constructor and is a shortcut from `Refile.backends['store']` and `Refile.backends['cache']`. So you just need to add the backends to the `@backends` hash.

```
aws_base = {
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
  region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
}

aws_1 = aws_base.merge({bucket: "bucket-1"})
aws_2 = aws_base.merge({bucket: "bucket-2"})
cache = aws_base.merge({bucket: "caches"})

Refile.backends["backend_1"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix:"store", **aws_1)
Refile.backends["backend_2"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix:"store", **aws_2)
Refile.backends["shared_cache"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix:"store", **cache)
```

So that's how you set different backends, and to use them separately you just need to address them by name in the attachments initializers.

```
class FirstObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :images, store: 'backend_1', cache: 'shared_cache'
end

class SecondObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :images, store: 'backend_2', cache: 'shared_cache'
end
```

Comment: Lomefin, so this code is working perfectly? I was having hard time figuring this out.

Comment: I could only make it work this way: `Refile.backends["product_files_backend"] = Refile::S3.new(prefix: "store/product_files", **aws)`. For some reason the merge method didn't work. But this one seem to be working the same way ;)

Comment: How is your aws object? How did you try to merge?

Comment: Exactly like you. Or this method requires pre-created AWS buckets?

Comment: Pre-created, I guess :)

Comment: Thanks! Btw, do you have your solution any advantage over mine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. Refile [has a registry where it stores the various backends](https://github.com/refile/refile/blob/v0.5.5/lib/refile.rb#L81-L83) and by defaults it uses a [backend called `store`](https://github.com/refile/refile/blob/v0.5.5/lib/refile/attacher.rb#L13-L14) which is [initialized on boot](https://github.com/refile/refile/blob/v0.5.5/lib/refile/rails.rb#L8-L9).

Since you can [configure the backend name per model](https://github.com/refile/refile/blob/v0.5.5/lib/refile/attachment.rb#L30-L31), simply register new backends (such as `store_foo` and `store_bar`) pointing to different buckets and pass the names when you configure the corresponding models.

Comment: Thanks. But when I tried to define store1 and store2 variables in initializer, it gave error - undefined method `store1=' for Refile:Module. Also, how can I map different models with different stores?